# Reply to an account when it tweets checking the id, tweepy bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I want to have a bot checking on a twitter profile so when it tweets i can answer them in the moment.
i've made this but i only get to spam the tweets already made and i don´t know how to check if it has tweeted anything new and reply to that new tweet. I need to know how to handle the id of the tweets so i can select the one that has been tweeted most recently.

```
import tweepy as tp
import time
import os
import keys

# credentials to login to twitter api
consumer_key = keys.c_k
consumer_secret = keys.c_s
access_token = keys.a_t
access_secret = keys.a_s

# login to twitter account api
auth = tp.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tp.API(auth)

#twit
def mainthing():
    toReply = #Screen name of the user 
    text = "hola"
    tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = toReply, count=1)
    while True:
        for tweet in api.user_timeline(toReply):
            api.update_status('@' + toReply + ' ' + text, in_reply_to_status_id = tweet.id)


#main-------------------------------------------------

mainthing()
```

Comment: You'd want to get the list of their existing tweets first, then each loop iteration you'd get them again, then compare that list to the originally obtained one, and any tweets that aren't in the originally gotten list would be the ones you'd reply to - and then you'd replace the original list with the new list. What part of that are you not sure how to do?

Comment: How do i identify the twits so i can tell my bot wich ones has to reply, i don't know how to handle The ids

Comment: I don't personally know, but since that's your actual question, I'd edit this post's body and title to include that information.

Comment: Thanks for The advice, i'm gonna do it